# How to get full page name in excel sheets when exported?

Tags: reporting-services

I have used Pagename under Group properties to get excel sheets with page names. when the name of the group is small page name is showing full name. But some of the sheets are like below

Stocks & Stocks Builders - Washington

Brighter & Lighter Shippers(DC Muller)

page name is showing as

Stocks & Stocks Builders -

Brighter & Lighter Shippers(D

how to get full page name even though if name is big. Please can anyone suggest me how to change the property?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will depend on what version of Excel you are exporting to, as Excel has a character limit on the worksheet names.  I would recommend seeing how many characters you can enter into your excel worksheet names manually and then formatting your values accordingly.